# Android App idle for 1 night, click on Push notification => java.lang.NullPointerException at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp

Tags: android, android-activity, nullpointerexception, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

APP idle for 1 night, click on Push notification
EXPECTED:  go to a fragment
Would like to know more about the cause of this crash

Here is the crash log:

```
USER_COMMENT=null
ANDROID_VERSION=4.2.2
APP_VERSION_NAME=1.0.10
BRAND=Xiaomi
PHONE_MODEL=2013023
CUSTOM_DATA=
STACK_TRACE=java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.aimpact.android/com.aimpact.android.AppMainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2346)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2398)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:853)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:417)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:452)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:444)
at com.aimpact.android.module.core.CoreActivity.pushFragment(CoreActivity.java:111)
at com.aimpact.android.AppMainActivity.tryViewGCM(AppMainActivity.java:864)
at com.aimpact.android.AppMainActivity.tryReceivingBackgroundGCM(AppMainActivity.java:842)
at com.aimpact.android.AppMainActivity.onCreate(AppMainActivity.java:312)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5226)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
at com.lbe.security.service.core.client.b.x.callActivityOnCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2310)
... 11 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:417)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:452)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:444)
at com.aimpact.android.module.core.CoreActivity.pushFragment(CoreActivity.java:111)
at com.aimpact.android.AppMainActivity.tryViewGCM(AppMainActivity.java:864)
at com.aimpact.android.AppMainActivity.tryReceivingBackgroundGCM(AppMainActivity.java:842)
at com.aimpact.android.AppMainActivity.onCreate(AppMainActivity.java:312)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5226)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
at com.lbe.security.service.core.client.b.x.callActivityOnCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2310)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2398)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:853)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My android code for Activity is like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    instance = this;

    setLanguage(null);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ButterKnife.inject(this);
    initNavBar();
    initDrawer();
    initTabBar();

    resetNavButton();

    onChangeFragment(null);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        AppMainActivityInitDecider.decide(this);
    }

    onMISC("UDID: " + Helpers.getUDID());
    onMISC("SECRET: " + Helpers.getAppSecret());

    tryReceivingBackgroundGCM();

    tryRegistrationGCM();




    mgr = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    registerReceiver(onComplete,
            new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
    registerReceiver(onNotificationClick,
            new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED));
}


public void tryReceivingBackgroundGCM()
{
    Log.e("GCM", "tryReceivingBackgroundGCM");
    if (getIntent() != null) {
        AimpactGCMModel gcm = (AimpactGCMModel) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("GCM_INTENT_FROM_BACKGROUND");
        if (gcm != null) {
            Log.e("GCM", "tryReceivingBackgroundGCM TRUE!");
            tryViewGCM(gcm);
        }
    }
}



public void tryViewGCM(AimpactGCMModel model) {
    Fragment fragment = NotificationActivityRouter.ManipulateEvent(model.getType(), model.getCode());
    pushFragment(fragment);
}




public static Fragment ManipulateEvent(String eventType, String code)
{
    if (eventType == null || code == null) return null;

    if (eventType.startsWith("1")) {

        ProfilePageFragment fragment = ProfilePageFragment.newInstance(code);
        return fragment;

    } else if (eventType.startsWith("2")) {

        ProfilePageFragment fragment = ProfilePageFragment.newInstance(code, true);
        return fragment;

    } else if (eventType.startsWith("3")) {

        ProfilePageFragment fragment = ProfilePageFragment.newInstance(code);
        return fragment;

    } else if (eventType.startsWith("4")) {

        WallSinglePageFragment fragment = WallSinglePageFragment.newInstance(code, AimpactConstants.PostType.STATUS_MESSAGE);
        return fragment;

    } else if (eventType.startsWith("5")) {

        if (eventType.startsWith("5001")
                || eventType.startsWith("5002")
                || eventType.startsWith("5003")) {

            // news
            WallSinglePageFragment fragment = WallSinglePageFragment.newInstance(code, AimpactConstants.PostType.NEWS);
            return fragment;

        } else if (eventType.startsWith("5004")) {

            // commentary
            WallSinglePageFragment fragment = WallSinglePageFragment.newInstance(code, AimpactConstants.PostType.COMMENTARY);
            return fragment;

        }

    } else if (eventType.startsWith("6")) {

        if (eventType.startsWith("6001")
                || eventType.startsWith("6003")) {

            // stock
            StocksPageFragment fragment = StocksPageFragment.newInstance(code);
            return fragment;

        } else if (eventType.startsWith("6002")) {

            // analyst
            ProfilePageFragment fragment = ProfilePageFragment.newInstance(code);
            return fragment;

        }

    }

    return null;
}




public void pushFragment(Fragment instance)
{
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, instance).addToBackStack(null).commit();   <<<   seems this line crash ?
    curFragmentCount += 1;
    onChangeFragment(instance);
}
```

Could anyone help me?